# How do I make this bottom image and text reverse vertically with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Please excuse any errors on my first post.

I'm currently stumped on how to make the bottom image and textbox reverse using flexbox. [This image is what I'm trying to acheieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVIoX.png)

I've tried using flex-direction: row-reverse under the .reversed selector, but nothing is budging. The style column-reverse doesn't seem to work either, and I tried it under all the selectors and still, nothing is changing. Here are my lines of code for CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .full-width-two-column {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-content: flex-start;
        align-items: stretch;
        row-gap: 1.618rem;
    }

    .full-width-two-column .reversed {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }

    .full-width-two-column .image,
    .full-width-two-column .content-holder {
        display: flex;
    }

    .full-width-two-column .image {
        aspect-ratio: auto;
        background-color: #dadada;
        flex: 0 0 50%;
    }

    .full-width-two-column .content-holder {
        padding: 1.618rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .full-width-two-column .content-holder .content {
        max-width: 20rem;
    }
}
```

And for HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="full-width-two-column">
            <div class="image">
                Image
            </div>
            <div class="content-holder">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Aenean quis lacinia nisi...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="full-width-two-column reversed">
            <div class="image">
                Image
            </div>
            <div class="content-holder">
                <div class="content">
                    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="windowSize"></div>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me understand this better! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: you just have an extra space in your selector `.full-width-two-column .reversed` should be `.full-width-two-column.reversed `

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize I had a space in the selector. This solved it for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to applied to `.full-width-two-column.reversed` and not `.full-width-two-column .reversed`. The property is good the CSS selector is false